# Kernel orthogonal to the image?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a self-adjoint linear map.

Is it true that $\ker (f) \perp f(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

I see a similar result for compact operators (Fredholm's alternative theorem), but I can't prove it for $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ using just my knowledge on linear algebra.

Could you give me a hint?

Many thanks!

Comment: It might require careful reading of the Answer on the proposed duplicate, but the hint is definitely there.

Answer (score 9):

It is simple, do it like this: take $x \in \ker f$ and $f(y) \in f(\Bbb R^n)$. So $$\langle x, f(y)\rangle = \langle f(x), y \rangle = \langle 0, y\rangle = 0,$$and since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary, we have $\ker f \perp f(\Bbb R^n)$, as wished.